# Изменить состояние проекта в Kohana

Tags: .htaccess, php, kohana

Пытаюсь изменить состояние проекта с `Kohana::DEVELOPMENT` на `Kohana::PRODUCTION`

Пишу в .htaccess следующее

```
SetEnv KOHANA_ENV production
```

Но в результате при переходе на не существующую страницу все равно выводит обработчик ошибок Kohana

```
HTTP_Exception_404 [ 404 ]: Unable to find a route to match the URI: media/xml/export/orders.xml
SYSPATH/classes/kohana/request.php [ 1126 ]
1121     */
1122    public function execute()
1123    {
1124        if ( ! $this->_route instanceof Route)
1125        {
1126            throw new HTTP_Exception_404('Unable to find a route to match the URI: :uri', array(
1127                ':uri' => $this->_uri,
1128            ));
1129        }
1130 
1131        if ( ! $this->_client instanceof Request_Client)
DOCROOT/index.php [ 109 ] » Kohana_Request->execute()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ini_set('display_errors', isset($_SERVER['DEVELOPERS']));
Kohana::init(array(
    'base_url'   => '/',
    'index_file' => '',
    'charset' => 'utf-8',
    'cache_dir' => APPPATH.'/cache',
    'errors' => isset($_SERVER['DEVELOPERS']),
    'profile' => false,
    'caching' => true,
));
```

У меня в bootstrap.php так настроено. Ты можешь просто isset($_SERVER['DEVELOPERS']) заменить на FALSE и всё

Answer (score 0):

В `index.php` или `bootstrap.php` найди строчку `DEVELOPMENT` (разработка), замени на `PRODUCTION` (продукт). Кто тебе сказал в `.htaccess` лезть - убей его :)

Comment: Вот откуда взял http://forum.kohanaframework.su/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=43

Comment: в бутстрапе только следующее написано
if (isset($_SERVER['KOHANA_ENV']))
{
 Kohana::$environment = constant('Kohana::'.strtoupper($_SERVER['KOHANA_ENV']));
}

Comment: да можно прямо в bootstrapе поставить `PRODUCTION` и все

Comment: удали это все и напиши просто

    Kohana::$environment = Kohana::PRODUCTION;

Comment: дописал ниже Kohana::$environment = Kohana::PRODUCTION;
результата нет

Comment: у меня работает...

Comment: Эммм...а поподробнее?